# Any method to resize my app's window on Mac (macbook) to 1600 x 1200 or 1920 x 1200?

Tags: mac, firefox, resolution, screen-capture

I would like to make a screen capture for an app (Firefox), but I am using a macbook, so the display is at 1280 x 800.

I think if I can somehow resize the window to 1920 x 1200, then I can use

```
Command + Shift + 4  and then space bar, and then mouse click on that app
```

to capture the whole app's window (which will be bigger than the screen)

So I can resize the window horizontally to 1920 by dragging the window to the left, and then make it wider by going to the bottom-right corner of the window.

But there seems to be no way to make it taller...

even

```
javascript: self.resizeTo(screen.availWidth+300,screen.availHeight+300);
```

on the Firefox address bar (URL bar) won't work...  it can make the window wider than the screen, but not taller.

Is there any method at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Paparazzi.

http://derailer.org/paparazzi/

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your bookmark:

```
javascript:self.resizeTo(1920,1200);
```

you may need to move it from the top left of your screen first for it to work.

Comment: that's the same issue: it can be wider but not taller

Comment: did you move the browser before clicking it? works for me on RHEL 5.4 and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the built in screenshot shortcuts: press Command-Shift-4, then press Space to toggle for capturing the window rather than the selection, click the desired window.

If you simply must have a screen shot of a website that is identical to the screen resolution, I suggest using the [Plainview browser](http://www.barbariangroup.com/software/plainview) (free).

If you want a single image of an entire website that scrolls down, I recommend [LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) (pay).

But, here's a simple script to change the front most window of any application that's in the front to change it's window to a certain size/location.  Remember the Menu bar takes up some space too!

```
--Edit these values to change the location of the window.  Remember the Menu bar takes up some space too!
property windowSize : {200, 200}
property windowOrigin : {100, 100}

tell application "System Events" to set FrontMostApp to (name of processes whose frontmost is true) as string
try
 tell application FrontMostApp
        if (count of windows) > 0 then
            tell window 1 to set bounds to {(item 1 of windowOrigin), (item 2 of windowOrigin), (item 1 of windowSize) + (item 1 of windowOrigin), (item 2 of windowSize) + (item 2 of windowOrigin)}
        end if
    end tell
end try
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Firefox add-on called ScreenGrab!
http://www.screengrab.org/